# Which is best converter (FT232RL vs PL2303). Reson?

Tags: usb, converter

Please tell me about the main reason for using the FT232R IC compared to the PL2303 IC.

Which is the best IC, and for what reason?

Comment: Look up their datasheets and compare... or search internet on "FT232RL vs PL2303". The **best** ic is determined by **your demands**. So, unless you narrow down this question providing datasheets and telling your requirements so those can be compared with **facts** from the datasheets, the answer to this question will remain Opinion based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why use of FT232RL module (USB converter) compare to pl2303, cp2102 module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472454/why-use-of-ft232rl-module-usb-converter-compare-to-pl2303-cp2102-module)

Comment: I tried lot of times to seen that datasheets but, i can't take main reason for this. that's why i am asking to u. so tell about main reason to compare this ic...

Comment: Surely the comment by MarkU gave you some understanding (on the linked question).

Comment: Nobody is going to do a blow by blow data sheet comparison of product A vs product B in the hope that scatter gunning will cover the one particularly segment of information that might suddenly appear to you as a game changer. Instead, list your requirements and go through the data sheets and tick which one is better at handling each requirement then, whoever wins (the most ticks) is likely to be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Best depends on what specific task you have for it, and you haven't told it. Both are USB UART chips and they in general both work just fine. In some corner cases there might be differences and how their drivers work under different operating systems. Usually you just get to know a chip and the specific quirks it has so you have learnt to work around them, and that is why you keep choosing a chip because you know it inside and out.